# How to read Torque-Power diagram for an asynchronous motor

Tags: motor, power-electronics, induction-motor, speed, torque

I'm sorry if my question is too stupid, but I am not able to correctly understand how to compare the information showed by the torque-power diagram with the motor test data for a 2000W Asynchronous motor powered at 48V.

[image]
[image]

If I am correctly reading the diagram, for example, when the power is P=1000W, then the torque is T=5Nm, but in the test data table, it says that when the output power is 1,06W (total power from battery 1310,4W), then the torque is 2,53Nm. I can't undertand why; Or, for example, when in the diagram the power is P=2000W, the torque is T=10Nm, while in the test data table there is written that at P=1960W, then T=4,83Nm.

How should I interpret this set of data?
Please, can you help me to figure out how to read this diagram?

Comment: When looking at the orange curve in the diagram, what is the torque when the power is 3kW? You cannot assign one value of torque to one certain value of power. \$ P_{out} = \tau \cdot \omega \$ and omega in (rad/sec) is proportional to RPM.

Comment: You should read the diagram as function of speed. At certain speed, the motor has a rated torque and their product yield a certain rated output power.

Comment: It looks to me that the curves represent safe limits of operation and the data table presents an efficiency test. If the data in the table is plotted, the results should lie below the curves. Outside of that, one is not related to the other.

Comment: I believe you're just having trouble with that style of graph.  The dotted lines are torque, and you read them with the scale on the left.  The solid lines are power, and you read them with the scale on the right.  The fact that 5N-m happens at the same height as 1kW is just happenstance -- the graph is not equating the two.

Comment: are you reading them at the same value of speed?

Comment: Seems like the graph is not to scale.